# Connect 1/2" Polyflex tube to hose bib

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, irrigation

I have a length of 1/2" ADS Polyflex tube that I'd like to connect to a hose bib. What adapters do I need to get this job done?

This is the tube https://www.homedepot.com/p/Advanced-Drainage-Systems-1-2-in-x-100-ft-IPS-125-psi-NSF-Poly-Pipe-X2-50125100/205903467
[image]

My preferred hose bib is the Sharkbite Garden Valve for the simple reason that it comes with convenient screws for mounting to a post or the side of a raised bed. The Sharkbite website indicates that the product is "Compatible with PEX, copper, CPVC, PE-RT and SDR-9 HDPE pipe." Would that work with the ADS Polyflex tube which is labeled SIDR-15?
https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/brass-push-to-connect/valves/outdoor-hose-valves/garden-valve
[image]

Other options I'm considering is finding some way to transition to something like a segment of PVC between the tubing and the hose bib or using a different bib and transitioning to NPT threaded adapters.

What do you all recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That type of poly pipe uses **insert barb fittings** (typically available in brass or plastic - a few stainless steel options may now be out there in the lead-free era) and stainless-steel worm-drive hose clamps (use two per barb for best results. Put the screw parts of the two clamps on opposite sides for best results.)

As far as I'm aware you'd have to transition to pipe threads, which will connect directly to a normal hose bib or boiler drain, or you'd have to adapt from threads to a compatible pipe type to use your preferred Sharkbite bib.

Comment: Your solution worked. I was able to find a barbed-to-threaded adapter and then transitioned to pex. I initially resisted doing this because pex is not UV resistent but instead I will just build a little box to shield it from the sun.